# Doctrine 1.2 can not fetch data?

Tags: mysql, doctrine, symfony1

I'm trying to execute query like this

```
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection()->getDbh();
        $query = "SET @sql = NULL;
                    SELECT
                      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
                        CONCAT(
                          'GROUP_CONCAT(IF(DATE(punch_in_user_time) = ', QUOTE(DATE(punch_in_user_time)), ', TIME(punch_in_user_time), NULL)) AS ', QUOTE(DATE(punch_in_user_time)),
                          ',GROUP_CONCAT(IF(DATE(punch_out_user_time) = ', QUOTE(DATE(punch_in_user_time)), ', TIME(punch_out_user_time), NULL)) AS ', QUOTE(DATE(punch_in_user_time))
                        ) ORDER BY punch_in_user_time
                      ) INTO @sql
                    FROM ohrm_attendance_record
                    where DATE(punch_in_user_time) between QUOTE(" . $fromDate .") and QUOTE(" . $toDate . ")
                    ORDER BY punch_in_user_time ;

                    SET @@group_concat_max_len = 10000;
                    SET @sql = CONCAT('select emp_number, ', @sql, 
                    ' from hs_hr_employee e LEFT JOIN ohrm_attendance_record a ON a.employee_id = e.emp_number group by emp_number 
                    where true '); 
                    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
                    EXECUTE stmt;
                    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;";

        $statement = $conn->query($query);
        return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

but get error like this

```
01/28/15 18:08:41,494 [3268] ERROR filter.ExceptionCatcherFilter - Uncaught Exception: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error' in C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm\symfony\plugins\orangehrmAttendancePlugin\lib\dao\AttendanceDao.php:553
```

The query works perfectly on MySQL, what's wrong with my code?

Please help!

Comment: I'm trying using $statement = $conn->prepare($query); but still not running

Comment: Do you really need to do this through a prepared statement ?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending each individual statement separately to doctrine.
Also use exec() for the statements that do not return results (like SET).

Try something like this :

```
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection()->getDbh();
$query = "SET @sql = NULL;";
$conn->exec($query);
$query = "SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
             CONCAT(
               'GROUP_CONCAT(IF(DATE(punch_in_user_time) = ', QUOTE(DATE(punch_in_user_time)), ', TIME(punch_in_user_time), NULL)) AS ', QUOTE(DATE(punch_in_user_time)),
               ',GROUP_CONCAT(IF(DATE(punch_out_user_time) = ', QUOTE(DATE(punch_in_user_time)), ', TIME(punch_out_user_time), NULL)) AS ', QUOTE(DATE(punch_in_user_time))
               ) ORDER BY punch_in_user_time
             ) INTO @sql
             FROM ohrm_attendance_record
             WHERE DATE(punch_in_user_time) between QUOTE(" . $fromDate .") and QUOTE(" . $toDate . ")
             ORDER BY punch_in_user_time ;";
$conn->exec($query);
$query = "SET @@group_concat_max_len = 10000;";
$conn->exec($query);
$query = "SET @sql = CONCAT('select emp_number, ', @sql, 
                         ' from hs_hr_employee e LEFT JOIN ohrm_attendance_record a ON a.employee_id = e.emp_number group by emp_number 
                        where true ');";
$conn->exec($query);
$query = "PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;";
$conn->exec($query);
$query = "EXECUTE stmt;";
$statement = $conn->query($query);
$query = "DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;";
$conn->exec($query);

return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I think it should work as is.